# How to get list of pods that are not linked to any service

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm, odk

How to get list of pods that are not linked to any service

Lets say i have pods:

`Svc1-green-xyz` and `svc1-blue-lmn`

Service `svc1` is served by `svc1-green-xyz`. With `svc1-blue-lmn` is a prior version of the same service and is not used.

*I want to select all such unused pods that are not serving any service and delete them. How can this be done. Is there a helm command that can be used?*

Comment: Deleting specific services is not a feature of helm. helm can manage entities tagged as a "release" which will include the services it has deployed previously. So if this service was part of an old release that was removed, helm should have done that.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but very hacky. Pods and services aren't really *linked*, so much as services use *selectors* to determine which pods they should target. What's really happening is that services keep track of a list of endpoints they need to forward traffic to. So, you could theoretically get a list of all endpoints for a service `kubectl get endpoints`, filter based on IP address, and remove all pods whose IPs are not in that list. If you're going through all this, though, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: It might be easier looking up the pods to be removed with the service selectors as the APIs/kubectl support querying that way... Still going to end up with some parsing and filtering either way.